# Print the sum of entered numbers

Tags: lisp

I'm using command prompt and notepad and I can't print the sum of the entered numbers.

I tried

```
 (format t "Sum ~d ~%" I don't know what should put here)   
 
and I know if I put num then there's no value
```

here's my code

```
(princ"Enter how many numbers to read: ")
(defparameter a(read))

(defun num ()
  (loop repeat a
        sum (progn 
              (format *query-io* "Enter a number: ")
              (finish-output)
              (parse-integer (read-line *query-io* )))))

(num)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of `...` below, `format` expects a number:

```
(format t "Sum ~d ~%" ...)
```

If you put `num`, this won't work

```
(format t "Sum ~d ~%" num)
```

Because `num` refers to a variable named `num`, which does not exist in your environment. You defined a *function* named `num`. That function computes a value when it is called, so you need to *call* the function named `num`.

The way you call a function in Lisp is by writing `(num)`, this is the syntax for calling function `num` with zero arguments.

Equivalently, you could also call `(funcall #'num)`, which is a bit different: `funcall` accepts a function *object* and calls it, and `#'num` is syntax for accessing the function object bound to the symbol `num`. In fact `#'num` is a shorter way of writing `(function num)`, where `function` is a special operator that knows how to return a callable object given a name.

In your case, you can directly write `(num)`, as follows:

```
(format t "Sum ~d ~%" (num))
```

The evaluation of this forms first evaluate all the arguments in order, `T`, the control string, then `(num)`. While evaluating `(num)` it will prompt for `a` numbers. Eventually, it will return the sum thanks to the loop, and the arguments to `format` will be known. Then `format` will be executed, will all its parameters bound to the computed values.